# Unable to close magnify pop up box in java script on page load

Tags: javascript

I am unable to close the magnify pop up on page load. When i click the subscribe link it opens the pop up and lets me close it. However on page load it does not let me.

I am using the following scripts:

https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js
https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/magnific-popup.js/1.1.0/jquery.magnific-popup.min.js

```
   <button title="Close (Esc)" type="button" class="mfp-close">×</button>
```

Current JS:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $('.open-popup-link').magnificPopup({
        type: 'inline',
        midClick: true,
        mainClass: 'mfp-fade'
    });

});
```

https://codepen.io/adar123/pen/BaooLLP

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To open the popup on page load try doing this way.

```
$.magnificPopup.open({
        items: {
        type: 'inline',
        src: '#test-popup'
        },
        midClick: true,
        mainClass: 'mfp-fade'
    });
```